# Parse upload to a class using REST java

Tags: java, parse-platform

I want to upload file to a class `myclass` in parse.com .Now, when I use the URL as `https://api.parse.com/1/files/hello`, I get the response message `Created` and the location of the file in the header. But, when I try to upload it to the class, I get the response message :- **Bad Request** and the header says that it is a `400 request`. What am I doing wrong?

```
    String name = "file.txt";
    URL url = new URL("https://api.parse.com/1/classes/myclass/hello");
    HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    httpConn.setDoOutput(true);
    httpConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("X-Parse-Application-Id", "App_Id");
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", "APp_KeY");
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "text/plain");
    OutputStream outputStream = httpConn.getOutputStream();
    File uploadFile = new File("F:\\file.txt");
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(uploadFile);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int bytesRead = -1;
    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    outputStream.close();
    inputStream.close();
    System.out.println("Response message : " + httpConn.getResponseMessage());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't upload using your class name I guess. What I do is first upload the file and then insert it into the class. I will be using Java since you have used java. So, first upload your file using `https://api.parse.com/1/files/hello`. 
Then you will get the location of the file in the header received. You can get it using `httpConn.getResponseHeader("Location");`. 
Now that will give you the entire url of the file. But you need only the name. You can extract it by this code:-

```
String ar[] = location.split("[/]");
String name = ar[ar.length - 1];
```

Now, insert it into your class. But before inserting, you have to make sure that you have a column that has data type of `File` in your class. Now, insert it into your class using this code :-

```
httpConn.setDoOutput(true);
httpConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
httpConn.setRequestProperty("X-Parse-Application-Id", "App_Id");
httpConn.setRequestProperty("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", "APp_KeY");
httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json");
String json = "{\"myclass\":"
            + "{ "
            + "\"name\":\"" + name + "\","
            + "\"__type\": \"File\""
            + "}"
            + "}";
httpConn.getOutputStream().write(json.getBytes());
```

So, you have to make 2 requests in total.